# Trying to setup user systemd service: Loaded: not-found (Reason: No such file or directory)

Tags: 16.04, services, systemd

I'm trying to make a **user** systemd service that runs a python script - however, when I try starting the service with `systemctl --user start shadesmath`, and then do `systemctl status shadesmath`, I get:

```
● shadesmath.service
   Loaded: not-found (Reason: No such file or directory)
   Active: inactive (dead)
```

Here is the contents of my `shadesmath.service` file, which has been placed in `~/.config/systemd/user/shadesmath.service` with permissions `744`:

```
[Unit]
Description=ShadesMath
AssertPathExists=/home/mikel/bots/mathbot/mathbot

[Service]
WorkingDirectory=/home/mikel/bots/mathbot/mathbot
ExecStart=/home/mikel/anaconda3/bin/python bot.py parameters.json
Restart=always

[Install]
WantedBy=default.target
```

I tried running `systemctl --user enable shadesmath`, which created a symlink to the service in `~/.config/user/systemd/default.target.wants`, but this hasn't seemed to change anything when I try starting the service.

This is my first time trying to use systemd, so chances are I'm doing something stupid, but I can't figure out what the issue is. Any pointers on how to set this up would be much appreciated. My goal is to have a service that runs this python script, and to re-run it on startup/if the script finishes or crashes - ideally I want this to be a user service as I don't want this running as root.

Comment: The issue seems to have fixed itself with some more fiddling (redoing the steps in the question) but unfortunately I don't know what actually ended up fixing it.

Comment: To get insights about issues do `sudo systemd-analyze verify NAME.service`. To me it reported that `WorkingDirectory` is not a valid directive.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After creating or changing the unit file, you need to tell systemd to reload it:

```
systemctl --user daemon-reload
```

This explains why a reboot fixed it for @noraj.

Comment: didn't really fix in my case. Reloaded the daemon, rebooted the system, disabled/enabled the service (and getting symlinks created). I get prompted a password when running `service myservice start`, even though I configured it as `--user` service. And after giving the password, it says that the service was not found 

Comment: @Kamafeather The `service` command only lets you control system services (as far as I know). You need to use `systemctl` directly.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem; logging out and back in did not work but the answer was very simple: just reboot.